# Fragment from FragmentActivity doesn't display background image on a few devices

Tags: android, background, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

So basically, I have an App which works on all my devices and emulators provided from google. But there are a few of people reporting no background image which makes text unreadable. Please help, I have no idea where the app goes wrong.

here's my FragmentActivity file (basic part)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
        b1.putInt("tabId",111);

        Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
        b2.putInt("tabId",222);


        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, fm, R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator("MAIN"), TabContentFragment.class, b1);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("massReading").setIndicator("MASS READING"), TabContentFragment.class, b2);        

        TabWidget tw = mTabHost.getTabWidget(); //this tabwidget is generated after "addTab", the one from layout is not doing anything        
        tw.setVisibility(0x00000008); // = "GONE"
    }
}
```

and "activity_main" Layout file

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"> *******//This is the background image I need to display********

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/padding"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            style="@style/btn"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            />   
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            style="@style/title"
            android:gravity="center"
            />  
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/down"
            style="@style/btn"
            android:background="@drawable/decrease"     
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"  
            />                                      
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/up"
            style="@style/btn"
            android:background="@drawable/increase"                         
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <RadioGroup 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/rg"
        >
        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/main" 
            style="@style/rb"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/reflection"
            android:text="@string/rb_left"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/mr"
            style="@style/rb"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/readings"
            android:text="@string/rb_right"
            />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the Fragment file which just 2 webviews

```
public class TabContentFragment extends Fragment {

    WebView wv;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }


        Bundle b = getArguments();
        int tabId = b.getInt("tabId");

        wv = (WebView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_content, container, false);

        wv.setId(tabId); 
        wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        wv.setBackgroundColor(0);

        if(tabId==111)
        {   

            String htmlString = "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>stuff</html>";          
            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("",htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
        }
        else
        {
            String htmlString = "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>stuff</html>";          
            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("",htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
        }

        return wv;
    }
}
```

Comment: here's the google play store link to my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xt3.lent2011, and if you want to try the app, you could download the apk file from http://www.xt3.com/files/Xt3Lent2013.3.3.apk and install on your device. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the details on the devices that are complaining about no bitmap showing, look for the VM budget. If the device does not have enough memory to hold the bitmap, the bitmap may simply be set to null (or no background). Given your symptoms I would say this is the problem.